# event schedule php MySQL keeping track of upcoming events

Tags: php, mysql

i have been working on event schedule with php and MySQL my goal is to be able to have the background of a website change for each event such as Halloween  Christmas and so on i have come up with one that will work with the month but i am needing it to workout the day to ignoring the year

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect(MYSQL_host,MYSQL_username,MYSQL_password);
mysql_select_db(MYSQL_Database, $con);    

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Event_Schedule WHERE MONTH(Start) <= MONTH(NOW())  AND MONTH(End) >= MONTH(NOW())') or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$Edit_theme_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
?>
```

i have tried adding Day in to the code

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Event_Schedule WHERE (MONTH(Start) <= MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(Start) <= DAY(NOW()))  AND (MONTH(End) >= MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(End) >= DAY(NOW()))') or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$Edit_theme_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
?>
```

But seem to ignore event
using template DATE in MySQL 
example 
2015-10-28 to 2015-11-02  halloween
2015-12-01 to 2015-12-26  christmas
ignoring the year so each year it will change on that month and day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope that i understand your problem correctly. The first thing i have seen is that you use functions in the **WHERE** on the database fields. This is not a good idea. So MySQL must read every record (FULL TABLE SCAN) to do this and cant use an index for this.

The second thing is that you not normalize the start and end date of each event in 2 separate fields to do an easy compare. You can store the dates from the application in second fields with an normalized year ie. '1970' so you can easy compare it or you use **PERSISTENT** fields in MySQL then MySQL can do it for you.

**Here a Sample**

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `nr` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_start` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `event_end` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `norm_start` date AS ( date_format(event_start,'1970-%m-%d') ) PERSISTENT,
  `norm_end` date AS ( date_format(event_end,'1970-%m-%d') ) PERSISTENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nr`),
  KEY `event_start` (`event_start`,`event_end`),
  KEY `norm_start` (`norm_start`,`norm_end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now we insert a row

```
INSERT INTO `table1` 
    ( `event_name`, `event_start`, `event_end`)
VALUES
    ('hallo', '2015-10-31', '2015-10-31');
```

**The Reseult**

```
MariaDB > select * from table1;
+----+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| nr | event_name | event_start | event_end  | norm_start | norm_end   |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  4 | hallo      | 2015-10-31  | 2015-10-31 | 1970-10-31 | 1970-10-31 |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now you can directly compare the dates

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE date_format(now(),'1970-%m-%d') 
BETWEEN norm_start AND norm_end;
```

So you can the events. The only thing is when a event overlaps a year ( 2015-12-30 - 2016-01-07 ) you mus put 2 rows in the eventtable.

Please let me now if this wars what you want

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for so simple and great work